# combination chart in ms access 2019 secondary Axis problem

Tags: ms-access, charts

I have made a combination chart in MS Access 2019. 2 line charts and 2 column charts as below picture.

[image: combination chart]

```
From_to                  Plan(Period) Actual (period)      plan(C)  Actual(C)           
            
FROM 01/03/2021 to 01/09/2021     0             1             12            2
FROM 01/10/2021 to 01/16/2021     10            0             22            2
FROM 01/17/2021 to 01/23/2021     0             0             22            2
FROM 01/24/2021 to 01/30/2021     0             0             22            2
FROM 01/31/2021 to 02/06/2021     0             1             22            3
FROM 02/07/2021 to 02/13/2021     0             0             22            3
FROM 02/14/2021 to 02/20/2021     0             4             22            7
FROM 02/21/2021 to 02/27/2021     0             3             22           10
FROM 02/28/2021 to 03/05/2021     0             0             22           10
FROM 03/06/2021 to 03/12/2021     8             0             30           10
FROM 03/13/2021 to 03/17/2021     0             0             30           10
```

```
  I have used Column chars for:
    First issue plan (this period)
    First issue actual (this period)
```

---

```
    and line charts for 
      First issue plan(C)
      First Issue actual(C)
```

now i want to use secondary axis for line charts but when i set secondary Axis for them in chart setting it does not show any chart so i have set on primary axis, I would like to know how i can solve this problem.

Comment: Should provide sample data as text tables and/or CREATE and INSERT action SQL statements. Are you using ModernCharts?

Comment: yes I am using modern chart. I added sample data.

Comment: Unfortunately I use Access2010. I can't even get the chart you show with Classic Chart. This is a design issue and there is no code to analyze so question is not really appropriate for SO. Might need to post to a forum that facilitates attaching file.